# reuse generators

Tags: python, generator

I want to check the central limit with dices. Roll D dices. Sum the results. Repeat the same thing for N times. Change D and repeat.

There's no need to store random values so I want to use only generators. The problem is that the generators are consumed; I can't reuse them many times. Now my code uses explicit `for` and I don't like it.

```
dice_numbers = (1, 2, 10, 100, 1000)
repetitions = 10000
for dice_number in dice_numbers: # how many dice to sum
    sum_container = []
    for r in range(repetitions):
        rool_sum = sum((random.randint(1,6) for _ in range(dice_number)))
        sum_container.append(rool_sum)
        plot_histogram(sum_container)
```

I want to create something like

```
for r in repetitions:
    rools_generator = (random.randint(1,6) for _ in range(dice_number)
    sum_generator = (sum(rools_generator) for _ in range(r))
```

but the second time I reuse `rools_generator` it is consumed. Do I need to construct a generator class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may be working too hard, and you are definitely creating unnecessary lists with range(). In the spirit of being a little more explicit than the genexprs above:

```
import random

def die_roller(throws):
    """generates throws rolls of a die"""
    for _ in xrange(throws):
        yield random.randint(1, 6)

roller = die_roller(10)
print type(roller)      # => <type 'generator'>
print list(roller)      # => [6, 6, 3, 1, 6, 3, 1, 5, 4, 4]
print sum(roller)       # roller was exhausted, generates null list thus 0 sum

big_roller = die_roller(10**5)
print sum(big_roller)   # => 3500238
```

I think that gets you the rudiments of what you are looking for.

Comment: -1: `rools_generator` is a generator. Notice the round rather than square brackets.

Answer (score 5):

You could do it like this:

```
for r in repetitions:
    make_rools_generator = lambda: (random.randint(1,6) for _ in range(dice_number))
    sum_generator = (sum(make_rools_generator()) for _ in range(r))
```

This creates a function called `make_rools_generator` that, when called, creates a new generator that supplied the dice rolls.

Comment: Assuming `repetitions` is an int, it will be a wee bit hard to iterate.

Comment: True. My improvement to the given code is limited to the function returning a generator. :)

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
list(list((sum((random.randint(1,6) for _ in range(dn))) for __ in range(10000))) for dn in (1, 2, 10, 100, 1000))
```